# Не обновляется TextView находящийся в fragment после выполнения onPostExecute в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Имеется `AppCompatActivity`, в ней создан класс унаследованный от `Fragment`, в нём инициализированы `TextView`, а также создан класс унаследованный от `AsyncTask` с реализацией 3 стандартных методов, в `doInBackground` получаются данные по сети, а в `onPostExecute` необходимо изменить текст в `TextView`.

Проблема в том что текст не меняется. Пробовал инициализировать `TextView` `AppCompatActivity`, вынести  `AsyncTask`  в `AsyncTask`, ничего не помогает.
В простой активити все четко работает, но во фрагменте нет...

Прошу вашей помощи.

```
public class ParkingInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static int sectionNumberFragment = -1;


    private static TextView about1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parking_info);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.parking_info_toobar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_color);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ParkingInfo.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getStringExtra("numberTabs") != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("numberTabs")));
        }


    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            sectionNumberFragment = sectionNumber;
            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parking_info, container, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView28);
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView29);
            about1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);   //Тип парковки

            ParkingTask parkingTask = new ParkingTask();
            parkingTask.execute();

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {

                case 1:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p4);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p1);
                    about1.setText("001");

                    break;
                case 2:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p5);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p2);
                    about1.setText("002");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p4);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p3);
                    about1.setText("003");

                    break;
                case 4:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p5);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p4);
                    about1.setText("004");

                    break;
                case 5:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p4);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p5);
                    about1.setText("005");

                    break;
                case 6:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p5);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p6);
                    about1.setText("006");

                    break;
                case 7:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p4);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p7);
                    about1.setText("007");

                    break;
                case 8:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_p5);
                    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.p8);
                    about1.setText("008");

                    break;


            }
            return rootView;
        }

        class ParkingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            TextView about6;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
               //тут выполняются некоторые действия


                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                  about1.setText("Проверка изменения текста");

            }
        }

    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 8;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
                case 3:
                    return "SECTION 43";
                case 4:
                    return "SECTION 5";
                case 5:
                    return "SECTION 6";
                case 6:
                    return "SECTION 7";
                case 7:
                    return "SECTION 8";

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас где-то ошибка. Большего не сказать - кода не видно

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: а почему about1 статик?

Comment: это не играет роли, я пробовал объявлять TextView в активити, а также AsyncTask, поэтому и взялось static.

Comment: Проблема решена, нужно перенести TextView в фрагмент, убрать static, оставить private.

Comment: @Nikita, вы можете написать это в ответе